# Jackson @JsonUnwrapped creating empty beans

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a complex set of pojos and mixins.

Whenever I use `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation, my deserialized beans still are created even if all child values are null. I do set my object mapper to not include empty fields.

```
 protected static ObjectMapper writer = new ObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY).
disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES).disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS);
```

This allows me to skip empty strings or null elements but not empty pojos (to be specific all pojos annotated with `@JsonUnwrapped` are serialized as { } ). My deserializer does use Mixin annotations with `@JsonUnwrapped` but my writer does not.

So I end up having lot of empty structures:

```
details: {
    hoaFee: { },
    parking: { },
    pets: { },
    utilities: {
        landlordpays: { }
    }
}
```

How can I over-ride the deserializer used by `@JsonUnwrapped` so that null pojo objects are not created, or alternatively, how do I not serialize empty pojos?

Comment: Thanks @Aurora for edits !

Comment: This is being tracked as a feature request in jackson:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/888 Thanks to tatu !

Answer (score 0):

```
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.valueToTree(pojo);
    Iterator<JsonNode> itr = jsonNode.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        JsonNode personNode = itr.next();
        if (personNode instanceof ObjectNode) {
            if (personNode.size() == 0) {
                itr.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(jsonNode.toString());
```

You do this to remove empty ***POJO***.

Comment: I did try something similar earlier. But it does not help. The json tree still has minimal set of values ( like no json for empty pojo ). But when i do like MappingIterator<RootPojo> iterator objectReader.readValues(jsonNode), i get empty nested pojos in RootPojo !

Comment: `jsonNode.toString()` can get json string without empty pojo. Have you tried?

Comment: ` if (personNode.size() == 0) {
                itr.remove();
            }` this line has removed empty pojo

Comment: Well as i said, the JsonNode tree before converting to my pojo structure ( via objectReader.readValues(jsonNode) did not have empty nodes. Its after the tree is converted into my pojo, i found null elements in final pojo ( primarily because jsonunwrapped is deserializing into empty objects ). Is there a way you know to override deserializer used by jsonunwrapped, so that i can avoid creating empty structure.